# Remove option from ModelChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms

I just got my hands on an user account create view that looks like this:

```
@login_required
def user_create(request):
    template_name = 'user/User_Create.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
      #this part is not important
      pass
    else:
        form = UserCreateForm()
        user_error = ''

    context = {'form': form, 'user_error': user_error}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

with the `UserCreateForm` written like this:

```
class UserCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreateForm,self).save(commit=False)
        username = self.cleaned_data['username'] 
        username = username.replace(".", "")
        username = username.replace("-", "")
        user.username = username
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'name', 'profile', 'redefine_password', 'name_created']
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(),
            'name': forms.TextInput(),
            'profile': forms.Select(),
            'redefine_password': forms.CheckboxInput(),
            'name_created': forms.TextInput(),
            }
```

My problem is that we have different types of users(Admin, Supervisor, Support, Normal) and currently, Supervisors are able to create Admin accounts...

My initial approach was to pass the user from the view to the form, like this:

```
form = UserCreateForm(user=request.user)
```

and in the form, I'm trying to delete the option if the user is not an Admin, like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    super(UserCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if not user.is_superuser:
        del self.fields['profile'][1, 'Administrador']
```

but that failed miserably, I got a `TypeError: 'ModelChoiceField' object does not support item deletion`.

I tried assigning it to `None` but that didn't work as well since it doesn't support `item assignment` neither.

Lastly, I tried assisgning it to a `forms.ModelChoiceField()` using the `queryset` attribute but I couldn't make it work.

Could someone shed a light?

**Edit:**
What I am trying to do is to remove the option to create an admin account in case the current logged user is not an admin, the option is defined in the `profile` choices.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing exactly what data you want to delete. Can you give an actual example?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, sure.